# Apply jquery function to current div only

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I've found the jquery code that does what I need - scrolls div horizontally.

So I have few divs, each of them contain scrollpane scroll, and what I'm trying to achieve is to get the div scrolling once user clicks on it. Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.section').click(function(event) {    

            $('.section').css('border', '1px solid #dfdfdf');
            $('.section').find('.jspDrag').css('display', 'none');
            $('.section').removeClass('active');            
            $(this).addClass('active');

            if ($('.section').hasClass('active')) {

            $(this).find('.scroll-pane').each(function() {

                var scrollPane = $(this).jScrollPane();
                var api = scrollPane.data('jsp'); 

                scrollPane.bind( 
                    'mousewheel',
                    function (event, delta, deltaX) 
                    { 
                        api.scrollByX(delta*-50);
                        return false;
                    }); 
            });    
        };

            $(this).css('border', '1px solid #4ea0dc');
            $(this).find('.jspDrag').css('display', 'initial');
            event.stopPropagation();    
        });

        $('body').on('click', function(event) {    

            $('.section').css('border', '1px solid #dfdfdf');
            $('.section').removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('.scroll-pane').css('display', 'block');
            $(this).find('.jspDrag').css('display', 'none');

        });
    });
```

The found jquery script is placed right after `hasClass('active')` part.

Code is working almost perfectly, apart from the fact that after clicking on anoter div, although scrollbar disappears from previous one, user can still scroll it (and the currently selected too). With every another div clicked on, user is able to scroll all previously selected divs when hovering mouse over them. And that is not what I need, I want only the currently selected div to be scrollable. Adding class 'active' isn't required if it makes code lighter.

I suspect it might have something to do with `.each()` part, but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: does plugin have a `destroy` method? If so use it to destroy previous initializations

Comment: There is destroy, but it seeems to be doing something else (ie removes styling from scrollbars). I still suspect the `.each()` part, how can I set it up just for that particular div?

Comment: Suugest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Not clear what behavior you want exactly, or what is currently happening

Comment: Tried jsfiddle but but to many external files involved. I literally want to have mouse horizontal scrolling when clicking on the div, and when clicking outside that div, the horizontal scrolling is no more possible. Currently funcionality is added to each CLICKED div without removing it from previous one.